# ¿Cómo sumar dentro de un Count?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) AS CANTIDAD_DE_TRAMITE, S.TIPO_TRAMITE
FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL A
   INNER JOIN SOL_DOM_TIPO_TRAMITE S ON S.ID_TIPO_TRAMITE = A.ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE
GROUP BY S.TIPO_TRAMITE;
```

Esta consulta me arroja el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero sacar el total de la cantidad de trámite la cual sería 90, pero no se como sacarlo.

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: queres sacar el total de tramites? sin importar el tramite ni nada?

Comment: Hola si eso es lo que quiero

Comment: no vale ni una respuesta entonces. Select count(ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) from (noseenquetablaesta); si no agrupas, cuenta todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `SUM()` podés sumar la cantidad de una columna o en este caso el `COUNT()`.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) AS CANTIDAD_DE_TRAMITE, S.TIPO_TRAMITE, SUM(COUNT(ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE)) AS TOTAL
FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL A 
INNER JOIN SOL_DOM_TIPO_TRAMITE S 
  ON S.ID_TIPO_TRAMITE = A.ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE 
GROUP BY S.TIPO_TRAMITE;
```

Comment: Gracias Colega era lo que necesitaba, Muchas Gracias, Saludos